# Reinforce to someone

Tags: meaning

What does *reinforce to* mean here? I have never seen that you can reinforce smth to smb.

[twitter](https://twitter.com/RobBAylesbury/status/1427596330852102148)

[Montclair](https://www.montclair.edu/cehs/2020/03/25/dr-gerard-costa-reminds-families-to-reinforce-to-children-that-they-are-safe-during-coronavirus-crisis-for-nj-com/)

Comment: The Twitter post (which have to be brief) is probably a short way of saying _reinforce the message_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not common usage in my experience, but *reinforce* can mean *emphasize*.

> The accident was also one of several since Clapham [...] that demonstrated the role of breakable windows in the death toll. RSSB research would later confirm and **reinforce** the need for laminated glass to protect passengers and increase survivability.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reinforce)

Reinforcing something to someone is a logical extension: you are stressing something, but targeted at someone in particular.